# Get length of searched output

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a `ListView` in Django to return all users that match a keyword(username, first_name, last_name) from `search bar` on my page. 
Code looks like this

```py
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'blog/list_of_users.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_name = self.request.GET.get('search', '')
        if len(user_name) < 1:
            context['all_search_results'] = False
            return context
        context['all_search_results'] = User.objects.filter(username__icontains=user_name ) or User.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=user_name ) or User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=user_name )
        return context
```

And I'm showing in in template this way :

```py
{% if not all_search_results %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    No User
  </div>
{% else %}
  {% for result in all_search_results %}
      {{ result.username }}


etc.....
```

And I would like to show length(number) of matched results on my template. How should I change my code for that?

Comment: {{ all_search_results |length }}

Comment: @Pari Baker worked! Thanks! I didnt know that syntax for it... I have tried same (), etc but I never though about "|"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `all_search_results` context var contain queryset, you can go for `count`,

```
{{all_search_results.count}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both work
{{all_search_results|length}}